# Video not getting played on Mozilla firefox

Tags: html, angular, firefox, video

Here is the Problem in my angular app.

I have video in my assets folder and using this like below:

```
<video id="bgVideo" class="bg__video" autoplay loop>
  <source src="./assets/videos/Sample_Vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

video format is of `mp4 with H.264 encoding.`

Video working in chrome,firefox,IE10+ fine when I hit localhost:4200.

However when I deploy my app on production to URL `https://mydomain.mycompany.com` then video doesn't get played on **Mozilla Firefox**.

On other browser its working fine.

The error I get is :

> No Video with Support Format and MIME type Found

and below warning in console of firefox

> HTTP “Content-Type” of “video/mp4” is not supported. Load of media
>   resource
>   https://mydomain.mycompany.com/assets/videos/Beacon_Video_V3.mp4
>   failed.

and

> Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: video/mp4

I understand firefox supports video format `mp4 with H.264 encoding.` so I made video in this format only.

**Also Video works on localhost as well as company intranet** when hitting (`https://mydomain.mycompany.com`) however doesn't work on internet.

Is there any server configuration needs to be done ?

**EDIT1**

My production server is **Apache Tomcat.**

I have also tried to copy my application on IIS server on some other domain (`https://mydomainIIS.mycompany.com`) here also video not working in firefox.

Do I need to configure something for Tomcat to run the video?

Comment: Possible solution- Clear local browser cache, Check with someone else ask them to view the page and verify the video isn't playing,Have one person shift+refresh the page and verify the video is playing,Tell the other person to just to a regular refresh.Maybe be video plays fine.

Comment: Already tried..and not working

Answer (score 1):

Try with this option it may work, I tried finding same format videos but I have not found any.

```html
<video controls autoplay  loop id="bgVideo" class="bg__video"
   src=https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4 width="620">
</video>
```

Comment: can you try one more time just stop your server if possible , clean it 
 and  refresh project and rebuild solution then test,it happens so many time that once application is deployed it takes data from cache  even we do the changes,it sounds stupid but possible solution just try

Comment: I don't know it will work or no, I found one link just go through it ( https://blog.fonepaw.com/firefox-not-playing-videos.html